# PostgreSQL: Dynamic Query into JSON Array

Tags: json, postgresql, stored-procedures

I would like to execute a dynamic query using 
the EXECUTE statement and put the result into a json array.

I am getting

> SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: malformed array literal: "[malformed array literal: "[{"id": "1"}]"
>     Detail: "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
>     Where: PL/pgSQL function ....

Here is what I have so far.

```
CREATE or replace function my_function()
returns json[] as $$
declare result json[];
begin
    execute '
        SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(t)) from (
            select ....
        ) t;
    ' into result;

    -- doing some stuff with the array

    return result;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: `array_to_json()` returns a single JSON document, not an array of JSON documents. I think you simply want `returns json` and then use `json_agg()` inside the function. Using `json[]` never makes sense to me

Comment: array_ag(t) creates an array of objects (from the rows). your right, array_to_json returns a JSON object. In my case, it looks like an array but it isn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the user "a_horse_with_no_name" stated. `array_to_json` does return a json object and NOT a json array.

In my case i could achieve what i want using

```
CREATE or replace function my_function()
returns json as $$
declare result json;
begin
    execute '
        SELECT (''{ "data": '' || json_agg(t)::text || ''}'')::json from (
            select ....
        ) t;
    ' into result;

    -- doing some stuff with the array

    return result;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```